# Image not Loading in HTML file generated by azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-http-trigger

I am trying to embed an image inside HTML which is generated by an azure function. when I run it in localhost I am able to see the image, but when I convert that to an azure function it throws a broken thumbnail image.iam using matplotlib to save the plot

```
plt.savefig(f'{basepath}/plot.png')
```

this will save it to a temporary path and then I am using it inside my HTML content

```
<div class="image">
   <img src="""f'../{basepath}/plot.png'""">
</div>
```

on inspecting the page also iam able to see the correct path, though not the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

converting the image to a base encoded version

```
 encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
```

and calling that inside the HTML worked for me

```
 <img src="""f'data:image/png;base64,{encoded}'""">
```